# Paginação em página estática não está funcionando

Tags: php, html, wordpress, funções, paginação

Os últimos posts e o *link* de paginação estão aparecendo, mas quando clico no *link*, a URL muda para `/page/2/` porém fica com o mesmo conteúdo da primeira página.

Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

```html
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 8, 'paged' => $paged );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="noticia-index">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="post-thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div></a>
            <div class="noticia-index-conteudo"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2 class="noticia-titulo"><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
            <div class="subtitulo-noticia"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
            <span class="icone-time"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icones/time-icon.png"></span>
            <span class="time"><?php the_time(); ?></span>
            <span class="icone-comment"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/comment.png"></span>
            <span class="comments">1</span>
            <a class="leia-mais" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> ">Leia mais...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
   
<?php endwhile; ?>

<!--  Links de paginação -->
<?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
```

Comment: Gabriel, apesar de existir uma [comunidade só para wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), caso você esteja fazendo uma pergunta aqui, não precisa você especificar a  TAG no título. Se você reparou bem, quando você clica nas perguntas aqui do SO logo abaixo já vê as tags. Então acho um pouco desnecessário enfatizar isso, considerando que todo mundo sabe o objetivo das tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver de uma forma bem simples, basta modificar os parâmetros da primeira linha para 'page' ao invés de 'paged'

```html
(get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

Nesse link fala mais a respeito

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters